# WebRTC iOS 13 Issue with Metal

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

We have an app that uses the WebRTC SDK for iOS. After updating to iOS 13, we no longer can render video (sound works).

The error we are getting is related to Metal: 
"Failed to create NV12 renderer"

"Metal: Library with source failed"
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/fc8c97f950a4fead4a5debe3c838942db1834010/webrtc/sdk/objc/Framework/Classes/Metal/RTCMTLNV12Renderer.mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has already being fixed in latest WebRTC version GoogleWebRTC (1.1.28913)

Comment: While this version connects almost every time, it was working rock solid in iOS12.